# Swagger, upload image as example

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I want to set an example using image file from local

here is my code

```
 @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(
                    name = "username",
                    required = true,
                    paramType = "form",
                    dataType = "String",
                    value = "Username Customer Owner",
                    example = "![alt text](C:\Users\user\Postman\files\KTPHD.jpeg)"
            ),
```

as you can see I'm trying to upload my local images as jpeg
I'm lost here

Answer (score 0):

Swagger UI does not support example values for file uploads.

Comment: then how can i inout images to swagger?

Comment: Users can upload arbirary files during "try it out". You just cannot specify _default/example_ file contents as an example value.